# What open access journals are there in the fields of psychology, neuroscience, behaviour, etc.?

Tags: publications

What open access journals are there in the fields of psychology, neuroscience, and behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of Open Access (OA) directories, journals, and repositories you can scour through.

Note: Be selective in your choices, as OA is ripe with Open Washing; [Virginia Tech has a good break down in the differences between real OA Journals vs. Open Washing OA Journals](http://guides.lib.vt.edu/oa/journals).

### OA Journals Specifically for Psychology, Neuroscience, and Behaviour

[87k+ Results for 'Psychology' - DOAJ](https://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22%3A%20%7B%22query_string%22%3A%20%7B%22query%22%3A%20%22psychology%22%2C%20%22default_operator%22%3A%20%22AND%22%7D%7D%7D#.WApdDpMrL_Q)
[Medicine & Health Sciences Open Access Journals - Open Science Online](http://www.openscienceonline.com/journal/index#category2)
[Results Under 'Neurophysiology and neuropsychology' - Open Science Directory](http://atoz.ebsco.com/Titles/Subject/8623?subjectId=28282&subjectName=Neurophysiology%2Band%2Bneuropsychology&resourceType=all&resourceTypeName=allTitles)
[Results Under 'Psychology' - Open Science Directory](https://atoz.ebsco.com/titles/searchresults/8623?GetResourcesBy=TitleNameSearch&Find=psychology&SearchType=Contains)

## Open Access Directories, Journals, and Repositories

[DOAJ (Directory of Open Access Journals)](https://doaj.org/)
[List of Open Access Journals - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_access_journals)
[SPARC (the Scholarly Publishing and Academic Resources Coalition)](http://sparcopen.org/) is a global coalition committed to making Open the default for research and education.
You should certainly join and ask the [SPARC OA Forum](https://groups.google.com/a/arl.org/forum/#!forum/sparc-oaforum/)
[OKF Open Science Working Group](http://science.okfn.org/)
[OKF Open Access Working Group](http://access.okfn.org/)
[PLOS (Public Library of Science)](https://www.plos.org/) [publishes many publications](https://www.plos.org/publications), [including a suite of Open Access journals - PLOS Journals](http://journals.plos.org/)
[OAD (Open Access Directory)](http://oad.simmons.edu/oadwiki/Main_Page) is a compendium of simple factual lists about open access (OA) to science and scholarship, maintained by the OA community at larg
[Search OAD Categories](http://oad.simmons.edu/oadwiki/Special:Categories), and/or [Search OAD Articles](http://oad.simmons.edu/oadwiki/Special:AllPages).
[OpenDOAR - The Directory of Open Access Repositories](http://www.opendoar.org/) is an authoritative directory of open access repositories, each visited by project staff to check/verify information that is recorded there. OpenDOAR's in-depth approach does not rely on automated analysis and gives a quality-controlled list of repositories.
[ROAR - Registry of Open Access Repositories](http://roar.eprints.org/)
[Open Access Journals - International Association for Media and Communication Research](http://iamcr.org/open-access-journals)
[OAJSE - Open Access Journals Search Engine (Excluding India)](http://www.oajse.com/)